# Round x to the nearest y

Tags: rounding

I have a number x, that I need to be able to round to the nearest y.

I need an algorithm to act as the function `f` for example where:

```
f(x,y) = output

f(1,3) = 0

f(4,2) = 4

f(3,5) = 5

f(3.2,0.3) = 3.3
```

and so on.

I have seen algorithms to work with specific x and specific y but they don't seem to apply to work in all cases.

Comment: Do you need this in a particular programming language, or...?

Comment: @2rs2ts Any that is easy to read will do, I'm more interested in the method behind it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had success with the formula:

```
output = y * round(x/y);
```

Which should be easy enough to convert into most programming languages

---

**Worked Example:**

```
(x,y)=(3,5)

output = 5 * round(3/5) = 5 * round(0.6) = 5;
```

Comment: So what should `f(3.2, 0.03)` be? Are you rounding to the nearest multiple of `y`, or are you looking to make your answer have the same number of decimal places as `y`, and have the least significant digit be a multiple of `y`? The former would be `3.21`, but the latter would be `3.20`.

Comment: @2rs2ts I think that as-long as the output is a multiple of y that is all that matters. So in this case 3.21 would be the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

some pseudocode to get your brain on tour ;)

```
for (i = (x - y) to x + y){
   if (i % y == 0){
     mark i
   }
}
get closest i
```

this does the following:

- it runs through "every" number between x+- y
- takes those which are divisible by y without leftover. As @2rs2ts already mentioned in a comment, the modulo operator does not work that well with floating point arithmetics

You can try the following in that case:

```
// this checks, whether i and y currently have nothing after the decimal comma
// to ensure the modulo operator works correctly
until ((long)i * 10 == (long(i*10)) && (long)tempy * 10 == (long(tempy*10)))
    i *= 10
    tempy *= 10
    increment some counter which is the power to 10 you have to recalculate to
```

and on the result you will have to calculate that back out again.

- then take the closer one of the two coming out

you will have to adjust increment depending on y's value, meaning if y is in the 1/1000 area, you will have to increment by 0.001, to ensure you get every theoretically possible number. You will have to evaluate how many digits there are after the comma, not the y-value itself

Comment: Modular arithmetic doesn't apply to floats so you will have to make note of the power of 10 to multiple `x` and `y` by, then divide your result by that again.

Comment: Yeah of course. My comment is only to elucidate for those who might show up and wonder why the modulus operator isn't working as expected!